# Windows 10 Antivirus and Threat Protection does not open for me

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe, windows-10

please help me I'm desperate. Download adobe media encore on youtube, in the video tutorial they asked me to place this command in the CMD this was:

**powershell -inputformat none -outputformat none -NonInteractive -Command Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath C:**

and after the program could be installed, I think it was already cracked.
But now at night I realized that my system protection icon has disappeared, I want to enter windows security from the start menu but it does not open, I try several times but nothing.
Do you know how to reverse the command I entered? I am afraid that my system is exposed, also I cannot format my laptop since I have many important files.

Please help me, I'm desperate.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling [Microsoft Defender](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/microsoft-defender/9P6PMZTM93LR?hl=en-in&gl=in)

Comment: start powershell and undo the exception: remove-MpPreference C:*

Answer (score 0):

reinstall your Windows defender by

```
DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Scanhealth
```

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Checkhealth

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

restart your device